# WCF Service using soap1.2

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have this WCF service that works fine using soap1. I'm trying to change it to run in soap1.2 but I have not been able.

I have try changing different things in the webconfig.

First, I change the basicHttpBinding for wsHttpBinding.  I also change the protocol, remove the soap1.1 and add the soap 1.2

How I can make that my WCF web service run in soap1.2?

Some code that I try in the config file:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpSoap" />
    <add name="HttpSoap12" />
  </protocols>
</webServices> 

<protocolMapping>
  <remove scheme="http" />
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Comment: Hello, The problem was not the project. I was using Soap UI to call the service. I did know that I have to modify the Soup UI  WS-Addressing setting for it to work. I set the Must understand option to true and check the add default wsa To: option. With that the service works fine using soup ui

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the project. I was using Soap UI to call the service. I did know that I have to modify the Soup UI  WS-Addressing setting for it to work. I set the Must understand option to true and check the add default wsa To: option. With that the service works fine using soup ui